# Mixed audio and video HLS

Tags: nginx, video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

There is video (without audio) and audio in a separate file. It is necessary to connect this video and audio to a stream and give it to the user in the form of an HLS stream or something else. Something like YouTube, there is video in 1080 quality - without audio mixed with audio track. Video and audio do not need to transcode, just mixed, so that the processor doesnt be used. Maybe you can do something like regular nginx tools?

Comment: you'll need to re-package... the HTML5 video element doesn't take two streams and combine them, it expects a single packaged source (be it HLS chunked or mp4). Something like ffmpeg is free, cross-platform, and will do a good job